# URL rewriting in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting

I am working on a project for a local college using MVC3. I have came across a requirement at which I am stuck and can't find any wayout. 
Let suppose my URL is www.abc.com 
The requirement is that if we type teacher name after the URL we get the detailed view of the teacher, like: 
www.abc.com/john 
www.abc.com/smith 
I asked for option like www.abc.com/teacher=john  but it has been rejected.
Is this something relevant to URL rewriting or some other wayout, as there can be many teachers in database so I can't make methods in controllers for every teacher.
Can anyone please guide me for this scenario?

Kind Regards

Comment: You need to learn how ASP.Net routing works.

Comment: Yeh I understand it my friend and am looking into it. Thanks a lot

Comment: You would've been better off with a maproute for this -> www.abc.com/teachers/john/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVC does this natively.

Just create a route for it:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Teacher route",
    "/{teacher}",
    new { controller = "SomeController", action = "SomeAction" }
)
```

Note that this will conflict with any other `/Whatever` URLs (eg, `/About`); to avoid that, you can use [my `MapDefaultController()` extension](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/09/using-default-controller-in-aspnet-mvc.html) to map a route for a specific controller before this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response, sounds like answer to my question, but you know when I will go in depth more things can come, so I will ping you at that time :) <br> will surely go for your MapDefaultController  Thanks Again