# Url Rewriting Dynamically according value in my database

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data-site

I have successfully Developed a Dynamic web site in Asp.net.
I have Renamed the default URL as Follows.

```
routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("Dashboard.aspx")
         {
             Action = PageAction.List,
             ViewName = "ListDetails",
             //Model = DefaultModel,
             Table = "SurveyKshan_Survey"
         });
```

The problem is I want to write URL Dynamically according to the value stored in Database 
Like if there is a value called NewSurvey I want my url to be like abc.com/NewSurvey and this page should throw me to the login page. Any suggestion on how to proceed.??
I am new ro asp.net any links regarding this would be appreciated.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Prefer this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637732/url-rewriting-in-mvc3

Comment: thanku Was looking for something like this.. but it is not in detail. any detailed answer will help more

Comment: Please help ... mstill waiting for a answer

Comment: I think it will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450944/url-rewriting-in-mvc4-with-razor-engine